# make a rectangle move on panel

Tags: java, events, graphics

I am creating a snake game, and I want to start at the very basic that moving a triangle on the screen. But I am have trouble on how to make a rectangle move across on the screen

Here's the code I have so far:

**Screen.java**

```
public class Screen extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    public static final JLabel statusbar = new JLabel("Default");
    public static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 800;
    Timer t = new Timer(50, this);
    int x = 400;
    int y = 400;
    int velx = 0;
    int vely = 0;

    private BodyPart b;

    public Screen(){

        b = new BodyPart(x, y);
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(10, 50, 0));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH / 10; i++) {
            g.drawLine(i * 10, 0, i * 10, HEIGHT);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT / 10; i++) {
            g.drawLine(0, i * 10, WIDTH, i * 10);
        }

        b.draw(g);
    }

    public void up(){
        vely = -10;
        velx = 0;
    }
    public void down(){
        vely = 10;
        velx = 0;
    }
    public void left(){
        vely = 0;
        velx = -10;
    }
    public void right(){
        vely = 0;
        velx = 10;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        x += velx;
        y += vely;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        switch(key){
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: down();
            System.out.println("Down");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP: up();
            System.out.println("up");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: left();
            System.out.println("left");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: right();
            System.out.println("right");
            break;
        }        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

**BodyPart.java**

```
public class BodyPart {

    int x;
    int y;

    public BodyPart(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

**Frame.java**

```
public class Frame extends JPanel {
    private static JLabel statusbar = new JLabel("Default");

    public Frame(){
        statusbar = Screen.statusbar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        Screen s = new Screen();
        BodyPart b = new BodyPart(400,400);
        f.add(s);
        f.add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setSize(800, 800);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

So when I run the code, the rectangle only displays in the center which I set it to, and it doesn't move. Is there anyway to solve it? In addition, the status bar also doesn't move. (There's something weird, when I put everything in a single file, it does work)

Also, I am planning to use `linkedlist<Point>`, is it possible to mix this program with the `linkedlist<>` ? or I have to change my code in order to use the `linkedlist<>` ?

Thank you

Comment: The problem is in the fact, that you not actually passing the new values of `x` and `y` to the `BodyPart` class. Since you only initialized it once, inside the constructor of the same class, hence `x` and `y` always remain at `400`.

Comment: oh it works after i put b = new BodyPart(x, y); in the actionperformed class, thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is the following:

You create the BodyPart object with x = 400 and y = 400 from that moment you only change the values of the variables x and y in class Screen, which is wrong because the Screen.x is different from BodyPart.x, so when you do something like Screen.x += 10 you also need to update the x variable from BodyPart.

A quick solution for your problem could be something like this:

Add 2 parameters to your draw method and pass the graphics object, the x and y updated values.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(10, 50, 0));
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH / 10; i++) {
        g.drawLine(i * 10, 0, i * 10, HEIGHT);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT / 10; i++) {
        g.drawLine(0, i * 10, WIDTH, i * 10);
    }

    b.draw(g, x, y);
}
```

Receive the x and y updated values and update the BodyPart x and y variables.

```
  public void draw(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawRect(x, y, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: This make more sense that I don't need to init my snake object everytime I run the actionperform,  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am not too familiar with Java but it seems like you are never calling the `BodyPart.draw()` method to update your `BodyPart`. Whenever you want to update the position of your `BodyPart b`, call `b.draw(g)` and pass the `Graphics g` object.

For the status bar, I think it will help you to know that the `main(String[] args)` method only runs in the main/starting class. It is intended to provide a starting point for your program. So you should rename the method in your `Frame` class and call it or you could move your code to the constructor of the `Frame` class and it will run when `Frame` is initialized

I don't see why you shouldn't be able to use a `LinkedList<>`.